# How to use implicit value with out passing it in to function?

Tags: scala

I was under the assumption that if, somewhere in the system, there was a value marked as implicit:

```
implicit val moo = "World!"
```

then it could just be 'plucked from the air' whenever and wherever needed?

Is this correct?

So if I now have the following code:

```
import Execution.Implicits._

def myFunc(stub:String)(implicit imp:String) = {

   //the compiler now knows that imp should be the same as moo
   println(stub + " " + imp)

}

myFunc("Hello")   // <- should print "Hello World!"
```

However, how can I avoid having to actually define the signature of the function as taking an implicit? This means that all the way up the call chain I have to include it in the parameters which just does not fit with the intended usefulness of implicits. How can I genuinely just 'pluck it from the air'?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, you can't.

Here are your options:

**Forwarding implicits**

Say you have a function that executes a `Future` and you need an `ExecutionContext`:
You can either `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global`(or define your own etc) in the same file as `someFun`, and you get this:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
def someFun(): Future[SomeThing] = {
  Future(something)
}
```

Or if you don't want to import in the same file(class, object etc) as `someFun`, you forward the implicit. This way, you can import it when you use `someFun` in another file.

```
def someFun()(implicit ex: ExecutionContext): Future[SomeThing] {
   Future(someThing)
}
```

**Context bounds**

Sounds like this is what you want, only you didn't implement it properly.

```
class Stub[T](name: String)
def myFunc[T: Moo](stub: Stub[T]) = {
  println(stub + " " + implicitly[Moo[String]])
}
```

The above is the equivalent of:

```
def myFunc[T](stub: T)(implicit evidence: Moo[T]) = {
  println(stub + " " + evidence.toString)
}
```

**View bounds**

Alternatively, if it makes more sense to implicitly convert a `Stub` to a `Moo` rather than bound it:

```
def myFunc[T <% Moo](stub: T) = {
  println(stub + " " + implicitly[Moo[T]])
}
```

To use the above, you need to provide materialized implicits(e.g a way to convert a stub to a Moo). For example:

```
implicit def stubToMoo[T](stub: Stub[T]): Moo[T] = {
  new Moo(stub) // or whatever
}
```

Bottom line, in your question usage of implicits makes no sense whatsoever. You can do the "thin-air" import as you describe, but based on the options above, see if it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

Then there is no need to declare it `implicit`. Consider this:

```
object B {
  val moo = "World!"
}

...

import B._

object A {
  def myFunc(stub: String) {
    println(stub + " " + moo)
  }
}

myFunc("Hello")
```

Comment: the point is that the value has already been declared as implicit. I want it to be implicit because I don't want to go back over acres of code to add it to the parameters of every function in the call chain. The code I have given is not the actual code, just an example.

Comment: @user3231690 if it is implicit, you can access it directly as well

Comment: how do I access it directly?

Comment: If `B.moo` was implicit in my example, you could just write `B.moo` and not even care if it is implicit or not